# Importants topics, research sites for algorithms, algebric geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

First of all, I am really sorry for asking a general kind of question. I have been trying to find out answer for this question from a long time. I have yet not got any reasonable answer.

I am an junior undergraduate student in Computer Science. I am interested in studying about current ongoing research in 
algorithms and algebraic geometry. Could you please suggest me some book on these topics??
Please suggest some important research papers in this area.

And a more general question, How can I know about current topics in these areas which are being researched now a days. Is their some site, journal which is famous for presenting the papers.

Finally please excuse me, If I sound silly.

Comment: "Resolution of singularities" can be done algorithmically in characteristic zero and perhaps people study how do it better. Resolution of singularities in positive characteristic is an open problem but nonetheless people look for algorithms to do it in special cases, hoping I suppose to get some insight into the general case.

Comment: If you are an undergraduate computer science major, then it is very unlikely that you will be able to decode the research literature in algebraic geometry.  I suggest speaking to professors at your university for advice.  In any case, this question is off-topic for MO, so I have voted to close.

Comment: I agree with Andy Putman that reading research papers in algebraic geometry is unlikely to be a fruitful approach. On the other hand, reading a textbook introduction to computational algebraic geometry could be useful. The one that comes to mind is "Using Algebraic Geometry" by Cox, Little and O'Shea.

Comment: thank you all :). I would be reading first the book given by Artie Prendergast-Smith